# How to stop user interface from changing when the language of phone is changed android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I'm using a UI where the location of edittexts for me is important. But when I try the app in a phone with Persian language as the phone language, the user interface changes automatically. I want my UI to be static on every language, what should i do? I am using relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your application shall not be affected with language change unless you have defined different layouts or strings in language specific folders.

Read through this carefully and make sure you have everything under default values folder

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I have not declared anything. they are all default values. but in a phone with a persian language as default it is NOT still the same.